# Inverse of $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{4-x^2}$?

Tags: functions

I tried writing

$x=\dfrac{f^{-1}(x)}{4-[f^{-1}(x)]^2}$

but can't make $f^{-1}(x)$ subject of the formula.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$y=f(x)=\frac{x}{4-x^2}$$
$$y(4-x^2)={x}$$
$$4y-yx^2={x}$$
$$yx^2+x-4y=0$$
Now use quadratic formula
$$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+16y^2}}{2y}$$

> $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+16x^2}}{2x}$$

Comment: Should the discriminant be $1+16x^2$ ?

Comment: How can any function give two outputs?

Comment: Good question, I hope you can find it out yourself @Mathematician171. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Q2d.png) is graph of $f(x)$.